# What is the best way to chain promises when using Angular's resolve: {}?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

I am using angular's resolve and would like to chain two promises. What is the best way of going about this? In essence, I want:

```
resolve: {
    my_two_lists: function() {
    return MyService.list().then(function(array1) {     
         return MyOtherService.list().then(function(array2) { 
               return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) { 
                    resolve(array1.concat(array2)); 
               }); 
          }); 
       });
    }
}
```

In other words: I have 2 services, each with two methods called "list" that return, well, a promise which resolve to lists. I would like to chain the two resulting promises.

Comment: Just deleted my answer after getting confused. Do you intend to use ES6 promise or angular $q promise?

Comment: @PSL - I thought you answered it really well - giving him a choice of either framework.

Comment: Do you really want to chain them? There seems to be nothing wrong with executing them in parallel.

Comment: What is this `resolve` function, did you mean `$q.resolve`?

Comment: @Bergi - He is calling `new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {} )'. `resolve` is the function you call when you want to resolve this new promise you've just created.

Comment: @AndrewShepherd: Omg, I'm blind. Thanks.

Comment: @PSL - My experience is that you have to manually invoke `$scope.$apply()` once the promise chain has resolved, which you don't have to do if you use $q.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something I've learned with Javascript promises - if you have more than one level of nesting, there will be a better way.

Here's a cleaner solution where you invoke the two `list` commands in parralel.

```
resolve: {
    my_two_lists: function() {
            return Promise.all([MyService.list(), MyOtherService.list()])
                   .then(function(values) {
                        return values[0].concat(values[1]));
                   });
    }
}
```

If, for some reason, you wanted to call them one after the other, then your example is correct, except there's no need to return yet another promise. Just return a value. The result of `my_two_lists` will still be a promise that resolves to the concatenation of the two arrays.

```
resolve: {
    my_two_lists: function() {
    return MyService.list().then(function(array1) {     
         return MyOtherService.list().then(function(array2) { 
               return array1.concat(array2);
          }); 
       });
    }
}
```